# Accessing elements of a 2darray in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

Hello I am new to matlab. 
How to access or assign values of a 2darray without using for loops.
I have working code using for loops. I read about colon operator but it can assign a value to a single row or a column in one statement.eg `myImage(:5) = 1;` will assign 1 to 5th row;

Code

```
myImage = ones(128,128);
rows = 128;
columns = 128;
for row = 1 : rows
    for column = 1 : columns
        if row <= 64 && column <= 64
                myImage(row , column) = 0; 
        elseif row > 64 && column > 64
            myImage(row , column) = 0;

        end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a logical index with a meshgrid!

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:128,1:128);
myImage = ones(128,128);

myImage( x<= 64 & y<= 64)=0;
myImage(  x> 64 & y> 64)=0;
```

Comment: You are a life saver. Thanks

Comment: @AnderBiguri Why don't you just do `myImage=ones(128,128); myImage(1:64,1:64)=0; myImage(65:end,65:end)=0;`? Isn't this way easier?

Comment: @Max Because I assumed OP may be interested in more complicated conditions than the exaplme posted.